# Can I give my creature Persist and Sacrifice it to Greater Good to save it from destruction by Beast Within?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Child of Alara](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChild%20of%20Alara%5d) and my opponent targets it with [Beast Within](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeast%20Within%5d). I then cast [Cauldron Haze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCauldron%20Haze%5d) to give persist to the Child of Alara and sacrifice it to [Greater Good](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGreater%20Good%5d). Does my creature come back with the -1/-1 counter or is it dead?

Comment: It's not relevant to your main question, but you need to use Cauldron Haze before you sacrifice Child of Alara. The order that you described it (sac first, then use Cauldron) cannot happen.

Comment: It's also worth noting that since Cauldron Haze can target any number of creatures, you could use it to persist everything you control, leaving your battlefield weaker, but still mostly intact.

Comment: @Erik I tried to tidy up your question and Title a bit. Feel free to tweak my edits if you feel that the changes are too much

Comment: The use of Greater Good here really doesn't change the answer. If Child of Alara died to Greater Good or died to Beast within, the same options and results would happen. (other than the token from Beast Within, which would die, vs the draw from Greater Good. Neither relevant to the question.)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for that, I was curious what the point of Cauldron Haze was... pretty sure Sacrafice == Die

Comment: @aslum Die in magic is defined as `is put into a graveyard from the battlefield` what caused it to go to the grave doesn't matter be it lethal damage, a destroy effect or a sacrifice.

Answer (score 7):

It's up to you. Since both of the leave the battlefield effects on Child of Alara are yours, you choose the order they go on the stack. This gives you two options:

1. Persist on the stack first - Persist goes on the stack, and then the destroy all nonland permanents goes on the stack. Destroy comes off the stack first and resolves, destroying all nonland permanents, Then persist resolves, returning Child of Alara to the battlefield with a -1/-1 counter.
2. Destroy on the stack first - Destroy all nonland permanents goes on the stack, and then persist goes on the stack. Persist resolves first returning Child of Alara to the battlefield with a -1/-1 counter. Then destroy resolves, destroying all nonland permanents including Child of Alara. A new destroy trigger goes on the stack and will resolve.

Usually option 1 would be the better option, as it leaves you with a creature, but if your opponent has a lot of persist themselves, or effects that make tokens when their creatures or other permanents die, you may want to use option 2, so that Child destroys all nonland permanents, including itself, making it destroy all nonland permanents again when it dies the second time.

Beast Within is put into the grave yard doing nothing no matter which choice you make, since it no longer has a legal target.